# setTimeout for specific hours of day and then stop until next specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, datetime

I'm running the following as part of a wider bunch of code where I want said function "tweeter" to run at 09.00, 13.00, 17.00 and 21.00 throughout the day.

However, when I run the code it will wait correctly for the "hour" and then it will continue to run the function instead of stopping and waiting to check if the next hour matches.

The workflow that I would like it to follow is

1. Run code at the hour
2. Run function if hour matches 9, 13, 17 or 21
3. Stop running until next hour check
4. Repeat 1-2

```js
var now = new Date();
var delay = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour in msec
var start = delay - (now.getMinutes() * 60 + now.getSeconds()) * 1000 + now.getMilliseconds();

setTimeout(function doSomething() {
  if ((now.getHours() === 9) || (now.getHours() === 13) || (now.getHours() === 17) || (now.getHours() === 21)) {
    tweeter();
  }
  setTimeout(doSomething, delay);
}, start);
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Answer (score 1):

you can use a cron job like this check the [doucmentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 0 9,13,17,21 * * *', function() {
  tweeter();
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Just playing around with timings now to make sure it's not looping through for 60 minutes at a time. 

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Went with a tidied up solution to run every three hours instead of on specific hour. Did go with cron.schedule at the end which is working as expected:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('0 0-21/3 * * *', () => {
    tweeter();
});
```